# Не запускаются несколько потоков в Thread

Tags: python, многопоточность

Не работают несколько потоков, запускается всего один, много вариантов перепробовал, но что то не пойму

```
import random, time
from threading import Thread

class Bot:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.gold = 1
        Bot.game(self)

        
    def game(self):
        print(f"у {self.name} | {self.gold} - денег")
        self.gold += Bot.gold(self)
        time.sleep(1)
        Bot.game(self)

    def gold(self):
        return random.randint(1,self.gold)



for i in range(10):
    th = Thread(target=Bot(i))
    th.start()
```

Comment: Прикрепите код текстом, а не скриншотом. Так будет лучше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не разбираюсь в модуле `threading` но так у меня все заработало

```
import random, time
from threading import Thread

class Bot:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.gold = 1
        Bot.game(self)
        
    def game(self):
        print(f"у {self.name} | {self.gold} денег")
        self.gold += Bot.gold(self)
        time.sleep(1)
        Bot.game(self)
    
    def gold(self):
        return random.randint(1, self.gold)
    
for i in range(10):
    th = Thread(target = Bot, args = (i, ))
    th.start()
```

Comment: да... спасибо.. хех